# Can I run the same instance on two machines, without connecting from remote?

Tags: remote

Just wondering if I can run the same Ubuntu instance on two machines, without connecting from remote. I have 2 laptop with both the latest version, same programs but I cannot remotely access to share or server outside the local network, one laptop always with me and a desktop. I don't want to work from a remote session anyway, I'd like work on different machines like as if were only one.

Comment: The only other thing - that I can think of - is installing your machine on a USB stick or an external drive, and then taking that with you and booting from that. That way, you can use ANY computer you want. Just pop the USB in and reboot the machine. Boom!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "connecting from remote" as a remote desktop solution, then yes, that is not necessary. You do need to synchronize them somehow, and we have solutions for that. For instance, Ubuntu One can be used to synchronize files between computers. There is also something called OneConf that can be used to synchronize application settings, etc.